# Is InvalidStateStoreException possible when state store is obtained from ProcessorContext?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

When attempting to obtain a local state store from `KafkaStreams` it's possible to get `InvalidStateStoreException` exception if the local `KafkaStreams` instance is not yet ready or the state store was just migrated to another instance (re-balancing).

Let's say we have DSL topology which includes local state store added by `addStateStore` and some process or transform (`KStream:process` or `KStream::transform`).

Below are my questions:

1. Could `InvalidStateStoreException` exception be thrown when local state store is obtained from `ProcessorContext` context inside `Processor::init` or `Transformer::init`, i.e.

```
KeyValueStore<ByteString, User> userStore =  
    (KeyValueStore<ByteString, User>) context.getStateStore("store_name");
```

2. We store the reference to `KeyValueStore<ByteString, User> userStore` and use it  later to modify the `userStore` inside `Punctuator::punctuate`. Should we worry about getting `InvalidStateStoreException` exception on any put/get/delete operations with this store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could InvalidStateStoreException exception be thrown when local state store is obtained from ProcessorContext context inside Processor::init or Transformer::init, i.e.

No. `init()` will not be called before the store is ready. Thus, an `InvalidStateStoreException` will never occur.

> We store the reference to KeyValueStore userStore and use it later to modify the userStore inside Punctuator::punctuate. Should we worry about getting InvalidStateStoreException exception on any put/get/delete operations with this store?

No. You can safely read/write the store. An `InvalidStateStoreException` will never occur. `punctuate()` is executed by the same thread then `process()` and it's ensured that the store is ready when `punctuate()` is called.